# Probability of comparison of two nodes after insertion in AVL tree

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

Suppose $K=a_1<a_2<\dots<a_n$ be a set $n$ distinct keys that inserted into an AVL tree $T$. The probability of any permutation of the order of insertion of the sequence $K$ is equal. Also we first insert $a_{40}$ into $T$, how I can find  the probability, $a_4$ be ancestor of $a_9$ or $a_9$ be ancestor of $a_4$?

Anyone can give me some hint? I try to find some hint about that.

Comment: What's the motivation for the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When inserting into an AVL tree, the existing nodes are not compared with each other, so the probability of comparing $a_4$ and $a_9$ with each other when inserting $a_{40}$ is $0$.

On the other hand, the probability of comparing $a_{n}$ to both $a_4$ and $a_9$ is derivable asymptotically by considering how many comparisons one makes when doing an insert, which is $O(\lg n)$, making the total probability $O((\lg n/n)^2)$, which is very small - $o(1/n)$.

However, that's true only asymptotically. To get the result for $n = 40$, you have to analyze the expected number of comparisons when inserting into a tree of size $39$. That probably requires some heavier math.

To see how this can change, consider the probability of comparing $a_3$ to both $a_1$ and $a_2$ when inserting $a_3$, which I think is $2/3$.

Comment: I think you *might* have misunderstood the question. My understanding (which I'm not entirely sure of) is the following. We insert $a_1< \ldots < a_n$ in the AVL tree in random order. Let $A$ be the event that $a_4$ is an ancestor of $a_9$ or $a_9$ is an ancestor of $a_4$ in the resulting AVL tree (after all insertions are done). The question is $\Pr[A \mid \text{$a_{40}$ is the first element to be inserted into the AVL tree}]$.

Comment: Oh, I was answering an earlier version of the question, before your edit. Oops.

Comment: (Just would like to clarify that I didn't edit the post, in particular because I was not sure about what's asked)

Comment: Oops, I meant before @Mohammed.Rostami edited the post.